# Compatibility of the upgrade of MSSQL 2000 to MSSQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, compatibility

Actually I have to find out the compatibility of the upgrade of MSSQL 2000 to MSSQL 2005.
The MSSQL 2000 was installed inside the Citrix box . I did a side by side upgrade by backing
up the database and restoring in my local machine. Now I have to figure out if the applications will work in MSSQL 2005.

Comment: You might want to re-title this question.  "Compatibility" is fairly useless.  I would do it myself, but I am not really sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to give more information about what these applications are, but presumably the easiest method is to redirect them to point to the SQL 2005 database and run your test suite to see whether they still function as expected.

Remember when doing the installation of SQL 2005 to choose a collation that will work with your applications (using a SQL 2000 compatible collation may be the best option here).